# Firebase Analytics not showing daily active users for Android app

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I have flutter app for android and iOS using firebase firestore, I have issue with analytics that not showing number of users they are active per day, I have read many articles about that but all these about iOS, but analytics for my iOS app working perfectly, but for my Android app it's always zero.

[image]

Comment: You  configure firebase analytics for each platform project: Android and iOS  https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=android

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

Just update your flutter version and your firebase dependencies.

Comment: I'm getting this problem too after my previous flutter update. May I know which flutter version and firebase dependencies you used to solve to this issue?